# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null - error in Chrome

Tags: javascript

The html part is :

```
<html:file property="claimUploadFile" id="claimUploadFile" size="50" />
```

The Javascript part is :

```
if(document.getElementById("claimUploadFile").value == ""){
            var messagePrompt = 'Some message';   
            alert(messagePrompt);
            return;
        }
```

The above code works fine in IE but is giving error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null" in Chrome.

Comment: What is `html:file`? What document type do you use?

Comment: You haven't used function or something assign ,so `return` can't be use remove that will be ok

Comment: @DavidJawphan - you've misunderstood the error. `document.getElementById("claimUploadFile")` is undefined because the HTML is invalid.

Comment: There is nothing error with that when I tested ! But return will throw error

Answer (score 1):

I think html:file is wrong and also there is no function in your code so you can't use return statement

```
    <form name="fileUpload">
       <input type="file" name="claimUploadFile" value="claimUploadFile" id="claimUploadFile">
    </form>
```

Js part

```
   var file = document.forms['fileUpload']['claimUploadFile'].files[0];
     //file.name == "somepic.png"
     //file.type == "image/png"
     //file.size == 254845

    if(file == undefined){
        var messagePrompt = 'Some message';   
        alert(messagePrompt);
    }
```

Or

```
document.getElementById('claimUploadFile').files[0]   // Does the same work
```

Check the demo : https://jsbin.com/rodano/4/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: You could even use `var file = document.getElementById('claimUploadFile').files[0]`

Comment: Hi, I changed the "id=claimUploadFile" as "styleId=claimUploadFile" and it worked. Thanks guys.